# Heroku: set environment variable WEB_MEMORY for node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I can read here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency#tuning-the-concurrency-level that for memory management

> The Heroku buildpack provides reasonable defaults through two
>   environment variables: WEB_MEMORY and WEB_CONCURRENCY. Both of these
>   can be overridden

but they don't say how to override them. I tried

```
process.env['WEB_MEMORY'] = 1024;
```

in my app.js file but when I push to Heroku I still get

```
512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
```

How can I override this WEB_MEMORY variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heroku config:set WEB_MEMORY=unicorns --app YOUR_APP_NAME`

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars